# C# internal access modifiers

Tags: c#

I want to seal of classes in a namespace. I was looking at the "internal" access modifier,  but this only seems to seal of classes in an assembly. Can I seal of classes in a namespace?

Or do I have to move stuff into an seperate assembly? But then I will have the problem of visual studio refusing circular assembly references.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no namespace-specific modifier. One option would be to use inheritance and a "protected" modifier, but having an internal constructor on the base-class so that external code can't subclass it. That might help.

Comment: ...after all if there was a way to restrict to the namespace, people would still be able to define the same namespace in their code and inherit that way...

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible with C#.

**Namespace-level members can only be either `public` or `internal`**

You can however, use nested class in C#

```
namespace A {
    public class B {

        protected class C { }
    }

    public class D {

        void E() {
            var F = new A.B();    // ok!
            var G = new A.B.C();  // error!
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the internal keyword and expose the internal classes to another assembly via the [InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute in the AssemblyInfo.cs file.

Comment: Except [InternalsVisibleTo] is still at the assembly level, not the namespace level.

Comment: That's true. But what I know, there is no way of doing this at a namespace level?