# Circular Dependency in Dependency Injection via Constructors

Tags: java, factory, circular-dependency, code-cleanup

I'm using Netty (4.0.4.Final) in a project, and I keep running into a circular dependency that I need to factor out. This question mainly involves the concept of factoring out the circular dependency, but I'll be using some Netty terminology throughout for those who are familiar. Since my problem isn't actually with Netty, though, I decided not to tag it.

Below, I've posted my code, omitting portions that I don't believe relevant.

### The Situation

I have a `MyServer` class that adds a `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter` to a `Bootstrap`:

```
public class MyServer extends AbstractMyServer {
    private Integer someInteger; //Using Integer just for example's sake.

    public MyServer(MyServerInitializer initializer) {
        //...
        bootstrap.handler(initializer);
        //...
    }

    public void updateInteger(Integer value) {
        someInteger = value;
        //Send an update packet to another server.
    }
}
```

`MyServerInitializer` needs to add a `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter` to the `ChannelPipeline`:

```
public class MyServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {
    private ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter handler;

    public MyServerInitializer(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        ch.pipeline().addLast(
                new ObjectEncoder(),
                new ObjectDecoder(),
                handler);
    }
}
```

I also have a `MyServerHandler` which is the constructor argument of `MyServerInitializer` in the case I'm speaking about:

```
public class MyServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
    private MyServer server;

    public MyServerHandler(MyServer server) {
        this.server = server;
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        Integer obj = (Integer) msg; //Remember just using Integer for example. Think of it as an Object rather than an Integer.
        server.updateInteger(obj);
    }
}
```

So, the circular dependency becomes apparent during initialization:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //I can't set a reference to MyServer instance here because it hasn't been created yet. I want to avoid the circular dependency here.
    MyServerHandler handler = new MyServerHandler(...);
    MyServerInitializer initializer = new MyServerInitializer(handler);
    MyServer server = new MyServer(initializer);
}
```

### Possible solutions

#### Refactor into `main()`

I could pull the creation of `Integer someInteger` out of `MyServer`, create it at the scope of the `main()` function, then inject it's reference into `MyServerHandler` and `MyServer`. This would of course give `MyServerHandler` the ability to modify it directly, instead of having to go through `MyServer`. The draw back is that it's been declared at the scope of `main()` now. I don't want to have to do this for every class member that might essentially need to be modified by a `Handler` class.

#### Create a `MyServerFactory`

One of the concepts I read about was to separate construction from use. This makes a lot of sense, so I gave it a shot with the below Factory pattern implementation.

```
public class MyServerFactory implements AbstractFactory<MyServer> {
    public MyServer create() {
        Integer someInteger = createInteger();
        MyServerHandler handler = createHandler(someInteger);
        MyServerInitializer initializer = createInitializer(handler);
        return new MyServer(initializer);
    }

    /* creator methods for the different components above. */
}
```

However, this seems like I simply moved the code from `main()` to this `Factory` class.

**Questions**

1. What happens if I want to inject a different `Handler` into `MyServerInitializer` - perhaps this new `Handler` doesn't accept an `Integer` as an argument. Would I have to create a new `Factory` just for this case?
2. Does it make sense to have a `Factory` that would probably only ever create a single instance of `MyServer`?
3. **Is there another option available to factor out this circular reference?**

The question in bold is my main focus for asking this on StackOverflow. I feel like I must be overlooking something simpler, or more elegant here. I'm hoping that some of you more experienced users can lend some insight. Please, let me know if more information is needed.

### Referenced Materials

- [Resolving Circular Dependencies with Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450997/resolving-circular-dependencies-with-dependency-injection)
- [Circular Dependency in Constructors and Dependency Injection by Misko Hevery](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/01/circular-dependency-in-constructors-and-dependency-injection/)
- Clean Code - A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship by Robert C. Martin
- Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software by Erich Gamma et. al

Comment: I'd think there should almost certainly be a cleaner way.  It's hard to tell exactly where the break should happen given my unfamiliarity with the framework and the less than helpful class names, but presently all of the classes are too aware of the other classes.  Somewhere there should be the application itself, and the pieces should register themselves with the application (therefore allowing additional pieces to also register without requiring modification to the existing classes)...

Comment: Either MyServer or MyServerInitializer should have a public method that points to the appropriate `handler` and then the class that is the registrant should call that method when it is instantiated.  Since `MyServerHandler` is aware of its container, I'd suggest trying to have it register itself with that container rather than having the associated knowledge split in to two locations.

Comment: As a quick follow up...you already have an initializer whose purpose is construction/wiring so I'd certainly question the need for adding a factory to glue the same pieces together.

Comment: I started looking at the Mediator pattern as a potential means of resolving my issue. My plan would be to place the `MyServer` on a `MyServerDirector` which would also house the `Integer` and an `IntegerUpdater` instance which would handle the updating of the `Integer`. Remember the `Integer` is just a placeholder for a more complex object in this example. It seems that the `Integer` shouldn't really even be on the `MyServer`. I believe in being on `MyServer` is is violating SRP. The SRP of `MyServer` is to act as a link between two points-not maintain updating of an object. What do you think?

Comment: I would certainly agree that MyServer should not be doing anything more than acting as some form of dispatcher/Reactor and you'd be better off having some form of service or something similar for maintaing objects, but it's very hard to say more without spending time dealing with the whole picture.  I'm also reminded now that you also seem to have a `Bootstrap` object which would be a second existing class that is dealing with construction/wiring.  I'd advise looking more closely at the relationship between the pieces that already exist before possibly over-architecting or catching patternitis

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I don't know much about Netty, these are just some thoughts from reading your code:

I don't see any problem with `MyServerInitializer`. `MyServerInitializer` does not have any dependenciesy on `MyServerHandler` or `MyServer`. That's fine. It would be worse if the constructor of `MyServerInitializer` would require `MyServerHandler` instead of `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter`.

If possible you should change the constructor parameter of `MyServer` from `MyServerInitializer` to `ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>`.

The problem is that `MyServerHandler` depends on `MyServer` while `MyServer` has a indirect runtime dependency on `MyServerHandler`. I would try to get rid of the `MyServer` dependency in `MyServerHandler`. To do this you can:

- Move the `updateInteger()` method from `MyServer` into another class, let's call it `IntegerUpdater`. `MyServerHandler` should use `IntegerUpdater` instead of `MyServer`. `IntegerUpdater` should have no dependency on `MyServer`. Using this way you would not have any circular depedency.
- Add an abstraction between `MyServerHandler` and `MyServer`. For example:

  ```
  public interface IntegerMessageReceiver {
    void handleMessage(Integer i);
  }
  ```

-

```
    public class MyServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
      private List<IntegerMessageReceiver> integerMessageReceivers;

      public void addIntegerMessageReceiver(IntegerMessageReceiver imr) {
        integerMessageReceivers.add(imr);
      }

      @Override
      public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        Integer obj = (Integer) msg; 
        for (IntegerMessageReceiver imr : integerMessageReceivers) { 
          imr.handleMessage(obj);
        }
      }
    }
```

-

```
    public class MyServer extends AbstractMyServer implements IntegerMessageReceiver {
      public void handleMessage(Integer i) {
        ...
      }
      ...
    }
```

Initilization:

```
MyServerHandler handler = new MyServerHandler();
MyServerInitializer initializer = new MyServerInitializer(handler);
MyServer server = new MyServer(initializer);
handler.addIntegerMessageReceiver(server);
```

Using this approach you would still have circular runtime dependencies but at least you got rid of the direct compile time dependency of `MyServer` in `MyServerHandler`.